# java : Need help converting an Object to Array

Tags: java

I have this Userlist Object with some data in it

```
Userlist userlist = new Userlist();
userlist.setUserlistItem(userlistitem);
```

Now  i have another Object UserDatalists  , the structure of  UserDatalists is shown below

```
public class UserDatalists{

    private Userlist[] userlist;

    public Userlist[] getUserlist() {
        return userlist;
    }

    public void setUserlist(Userlist[] userlist) {
        this.userlist = userlist;
    }

}
```

As you can see that the UserDatalists Object accepts an array of Userlist .

Please tell me how can i convert the Userlist  to an array , so that i can set it inside the UserDatalists

```
public class Userlist {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserlistItem[] getUserlistItem() {
        return UserlistItem;
    }

    public void setUserlistItem(UserlistItem[] userlistItem) {
        UserlistItem = userlistItem;
    }

    private String id;
    private UserlistItem[] UserlistItem;

}






 public class UserDatalists {

        private Userlist[] userlist;

        public Userlist[] getUserlist() {
            return userlist;
        }

        public void setUserlist(Userlist[] userlist) {
            this.userlist = userlist;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the concepts of `Object` and `Object array` in here...

Comment: "Userlist to an array"? an array of what? you cannot convert your defined userlist instances to an array.

Comment: You want an array of *multiple userlists*? Or you want an array with containing the *items* of the userlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowed to, change the signature of

```
public void setUserlist(Userlist[] userlist) {
```

to

```
public void setUserlist(Userlist ... userlist) {
```

which is effectively the same but allows you to provide single and multiple parameters or just arrays to the method.

Alternatively run the method like this:

```
obj.setUserlist (new Userlist[] { userlist });
```